# How to connect an Amazon-Alexa skill to Lambda and dynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'm learning Amazon Alexa and trying to connect the code to Lambda and dynamoDB. I've done some research in the last few days but the only tutorials I can find are from 2017-2018.

Maybe I haven't found the right tutorial, but is anyone here willing to explain to me how I can take the input from the user and store it to dynamoDB?

Also how to connect them together in order to perform actions on that database. For example, how do I ask the user to input name and birthday days which will be stored on the DB?

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/voice-tech-podcast/writing-an-alexa-skill-with-crud-functionality-using-dynamo-db-serverless-and-aws-lambdas-468e3358e24d)
It's from 2019 and explains how to set up in detail.

So how far did you got? You have already a running skill without DB connection?
If not, you should start with a simple skill, e.g. [hello world skill](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-hello-world).
Later you can add dynamo db and things like [dialoge management](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/delegate-dialog-to-alexa.html) to collect the birthday and user name.

Because your values you want to store seems to be specific for the user. Alexa SDK is helping with that, see ["Managing Attributes"](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/manage-attributes.html)

Comment: At the moment, I have the code to get the inputs from the user, but I want to store those values in a dynamoDB. values like: name, day, month.

Comment: ok, so you can handle this completely independent from Alexa stuff. Just google for node.js and dynamoDB. There are official libraries: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.html. Or what I suggested use the "Alexa Managing Attributes" if this is enough for your skill.